# How to include tests in project B from dependent project A and have them recognized by Maven "as is"

Tags: java, maven, junit4

I have a (Maven) project B dependent on project A. Project A packages its tests into a jar, as described [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html). Suppose I have a test class `com.forelight.a.FooTest` in projecet A. The class is visible on the test-scoped class path in project B, but is not automatically execute by `mvn test`. I can extend FooTest in project B's `test/main/java` directory like so:

```
package com.forelight.b;
public class FooBarTest extends com.forelight.a.FooTest {}
```

This does the job (`mvn test` runs this both command line and under eclipse) but feels kludgy.

Comment: Why do you need to execute A's tests in B's context?

Comment: @RomanVottner: The actual use case is rather extravagant. I am migrating a working "thick" API, i.e. one you have to compile with, to a "thin" one: i.e. one that's just a thin HTTP client to a micro-service. I'm keeping the signatures of all the methods unchanged, and expect to test the thin API with the same test cases as I have for the existing thick API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working automated solution:

- project A should also provide its [test-sources](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/test-jar-mojo.html) jar
- project B should import project A in test scope and also import project A test sources in test scope
- project B would use the [`unpack-dependencies`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-dependencies-mojo.html) of the Maven Dependencies Plugin to automatically unpack the test-sources jar to a subfolder of the target folder (say `project-a-test-sources`)
- project B would use the [`add-test-source`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/add-test-source-mojo.html) goal of the Build Helper Maven Plugin to add automatically the unpacked sources as test sources in project A
- Maven will then compile and run the added sources as part of project B tests

To achieve it, in project A add the following to the build section:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This will actually create a new jar as part of the build providing test sources. Remember to install it via `mvn install`.

In project B, add the following to the dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-a</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-a</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <classifier>test-sources</classifier>
</dependency>
```

So that the classpath will be populated with project A, the second dependency is harmless, it will be used by the plugin execution below.

In project B, also add the following to the build section:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>unpack-test-sources</id>
                <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <includeGroupIds>com.sample</includeGroupIds>
                    <includeArtifactIds>project-a</includeArtifactIds>
                    <includeScope>test</includeScope>
                    <includeClassifiers>test-sources</includeClassifiers>
                    <outputDirectory>
                        ${project.build.directory}/project-a-test-sources
                    </outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>add-test-source</id>
                <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        <source>${project.build.directory}/project-a-test-sources</source>
                    </sources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Here we are unpacking sources and adding them as test sources.

Maven will then automatically execute the added tests.

Few considerations on this approach:

- It might look as kludgy as the approach you mentioned in your question, even though it would be automated and would not require to create new extension tests
- It's definitely not something standard, but the original requirement also doesn't sound like a standard practice neither
- You may have conflicts on test names or resources names (again, because it's not a standard approach)
- You may not want to run these external tests as part of your default build, in this case you could move the configuration above to a [Maven profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html), say `run-project-a-tests` and execute them only upon desire via `-Prun-project-a-tests`. This will also make your default build faster (and more standard).

Comment: @Forelight I added a further consideration about moving it to a profile, it might be helpful. If the overall solution meets your needs, please also consider accepting the answer so that it doesn't count as unanswered in the global search. Thanks

Comment: Ah, I never new what that checkmark is for!  Thanks again for your very detailed answer.